# What causes diamagnetism?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

What makes a diamagnetic substance repel a magnet? If one explains it on the basis of cancelation of dipole moments in an atom and Lenz's law, shouldn't the diamagnetic substance be attracted to the magnet when the magnet is moving away from it? But that does not seem to be the case...

Comment: You can find a very nice discussion of diamagnetism in the [Feynman Lectures on Physics, vol. 2, sec. 34](http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_34.html)

Comment: Feynman really did explain it very clearly. One doubt I still have though is will a diamagnetic substance be attracted to a magnet if the magnet is moving away from it (or the magnetic field around is falling)?

Comment: Aren't the induced dipole moments opposite to the applied magnetic field cause dismagnetism?